# Changing WCF Base address

Tags: wcf

By default the base address for my test wcf application is

```
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/evalservice
```

but when I remove the Design_Time_Addresses and go for a simple base address like below

```
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/evalservice" />
```

I receive the below error

```
Please try changing the HTTP port to 8732 or running as Administrator.
System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8732/evalservice/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
```

and when I move it back to Design_Time_Addresses the issue is resolved.

What is Design_Time_Addresses and how can I change it to a more simple base address?

Answer (score 7):

The Design_Time_Addresses namespace [is automatically registered by the .NET framework to allow users without administrator privileges to develop WCF services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2008/01/27/design-time-addresses-url-in-wcf-net-3-5.aspx):

> You can modify access using the netsh.exe tool [...] under the elevated administrator account. The following is an example of using netsh.exe.
>
> `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9002/MyService user=<domain>\<user>`

Another workaround would be to run Visual Studio as administrator.